# Подключение к локальной сети

Tags: localhost

я сделал сайт на реакте и хочу сделать так чтоб друг который находится долеко от меня смог к нему подключится. При этом чтоб было необязательно иметь какоето доменное имя , днс или статичный айпи, и чтоб файлы сайта ему тоже не приходилось скидывать. Или же както подключить его к локальной сети.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специально для таких целей - показать сделанную работу кому то, не выкладывая её на хостинг - есть сервис [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/)

Работает он так: вы регистрируетесь на сервисе и ставите клиент . При регистрации Вам выдаётся ключ.

Когда клиент запускается с этим ключём - то создаётся ВРЕМЕННОЕ имя вида `http://4.tcp.ngrok.io:15288`, Ваш друг вводит этот адрес в свой барузер, и траффик маршрутизируется на вашу машину через защищенный канал, который установил клиент ngrok'а.